# Developing for Google Glass and incorperating googles app engine

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, optimization, google-mirror-api

After watching this **[excellent video on google glass](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNo3DgKo3Gg&feature=c4-overview&list=UUkQX1tChV7Z7l1LFF4L9j_g&hd=1)** and Rails development.  I learned sooo much about how to design and create for glass.  Being a new to Rails but getting my bearings I want to figure out how to invest my research time.  That being said, my questions is about optimizations between rails and native app engine support:

Since I/O 2013 Google announced the huge overhaul to app engine.  Especially with the new support of PHP in app engine.  While I love Rails, it's not far from from PHP  frameworks like Laravel; other than the larger support of Rails.  Setting support aside and focusing on optimizations:

- **wouldn't it be in the developers best interest to use app engine in the log run when developing for Google glass?**
- **Seeing that app engine doesn't support rails would it not be advantageous to develop in native app engine languages such as: php, go, java, python, google dart??**

*I have no idea why this would be faster other than maybe a less request.  But better is better at this point because I'm so new to it all.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mirror API is a web REST API: this means that the underlying protocol relies on HTTP requests with JSON as the data representation.

There are many client libraries in many languages that you can use to communicate with the Mirror API and most of them are listed in our [downloads page](https://developers.google.com/glass/downloads/) and have inline code snippets in our [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/).

Bottom line, coding in Ruby is not a requirement, you can use your preferred language as long as you can send HTTP requests.